# Rails Dynamic form - Adding serializable fields to a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization

I have a `User` and `Setting`. `Setting` has a `:serializable` field called `:custom_links`:

In `Setting.rb`

```
  serialize :custom_links, Hash
```

In `User.rb`

```
has_one :setting, dependent: :destroy
```

I'd like to create a form that allows users to set any number of custom links, and store those in the `:custom_links` hash. Each custom link has a Name and a URL in the hash.

I'm not sure how to structure this form in the view and allow users to dynamically add as many custom links as they want using javascript (and save those in the :custom_links hash). I have other fields in `:setting` and I have my controller working fine with those fields - I think the only thing I need help with is the view and javascript.

**UPDATE for clarification:**

When a user completes the form to enter `:custom_links`, I'd like it to be in the following format:

```
{
:name => "Google", :url => "http://www.google.com",
:name => "Twitter", :url => "http://www.twitter.com"
}
```

Also, I'd like to be able to dynamically add 2 text fields for each `:custom_link` that the user wants to enter.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is using serialized attributes a hard requirement? You could add a ```has_many :custom_links``` association and use nested attributes to nest them under the main setting form. Serializing them goes against what Rails provides and will usually result in more pain in the long run. Also, I think you want to have a serialized Array not a Hash (right?). The Hash you added in your update does not make any sense as it has duplicate keys.

Comment: I suppose I could, but I just don't want to overdo it with the models. Not sure what's right in this case, but I thought a serialized object would be better. Also, the format (Hash or Array) doesn't really matter for me either.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with serializing them, but since it's a collection (not a hash), it makes sense to use what Rails provides. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding those links as a separate model (eg. `has_many :custom_links`). As an extra, you'll be able to use AR's validations instead of making your own custom validation methods for the serialized attribute.

You can use [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) for these fields. Take at look at the following railscasts episodes:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

The second one also shows you how to dynamically add more fields with javascript.

Comment: Yeah. Looks like the best option. Thanks.

Comment: Successfully implemented using Railscasts 197. Thanks again.